# Uniquely identify files before uploading with the HTML5 file API

Tags: javascript, html, upload, fingerprinting

I'm building a file uploader using the HTML5 file API. I want to be sure no duplicate files are uploaded, based on the actual data they contain. This means two files should be considered identical even if their name is different or are located in a different folder.

I have considered calculating a hash with md5 but because this all has to happen on the client side, with javascript, bigger files will take too long. When I say big, I mean up to 5GBs worth of video.

Just to be clear, this does not have to involve a checksum, I just want to uniquely identify files. Hashing might be overkill for this purpose but it was the first thing that came to mind.

*Update:* I guess I need a lightweight [fingerprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_%28computing%29) algorithm. I found [Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_fingerprint) as an example on Wikipedia but I have no idea how I would implement this in javascript.

Comment: Good question, but a hash is the only thing that comes to mind. You can't check if a file is unique without checking each byte, so ultimately you can't avoid going through the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

No shortcuts exist. If you need to recognize duplicate files with zero ambiguity, then you have to read and compare the full content of the files.

But if you can live with some level of false positives, then you may take some strategies.  For a similar problem I calculate the MD5 hash for a given subset of file blocks (using a predefined invariant window).

Comment: I've thought of this as well, but I'm not sure what the best subset would be. You obviously want to avoid headers and footers of a file. How did you determine your subset to minimize the chance for false positives?

Comment: I'm affraid that will ultimately depend on the type of the file. It could happen that some of the file formats would store some kind of identification tags, including some kind of hash in the header or the footer (I'm thinking on mp3 id tags f.ex.)

Comment: For my use-case it has to work for different media and file types. The best way that I can come up with is taking a sample of bytes offset to half the file size, minus half the sample size.